# Read user (not app) settings from another accessible C# app

Tags: c#, .net, linqpad

Say I have two apps A and B. App A has standard `Settings.settings` type of configuration. I have made A's settings `public` (instead of default `internal`). Referencing A in B and going for the `A.Settings.Default` yields only the design-time default values. There are no saved user settings. Invoking `Reload` has no effect.

Even simpler, importing a reference to A in [`LINQPad`](http://www.linqpad.net/) and dumping `A.Settings.Default` only shows default values. So effectively same as above.

I have found several similar questions even here on SO but none were with definite answers. Is there a simple way to do what seems to be a trivial task?

Comment: Very sorry. I first misunderstood your question, but now fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your apps are A.exe and B.exe.

B.exe references A.exe.

When I run A.exe, it reads / writes the user settings to / from:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\A\A.exe_Url_ify12bcwso2vevlc4wawlllokphlsntr\1.0.0.0\user.config
```

When I run B.exe, it reads / writes the user settings (of A.exe) to / from:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\B\B.exe_Url_vhnd4ku3yt2pxsldv3qsblquadzyhg3g\1.0.0.0\user.config
```

I got these paths by monitoring disk activity of A and B exes with procmon.exe

As you can see, the logic behind the user settings is actually the same as app settings. The runtime is using the currently executing process's name to store the user settings, therefore it is not possible to access A.exe's settings from B.exe as they were saved from A.exe.

Here is the code I tested:

A.exe:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A.Settings1.Default.AExeSetting1: {0}", A.Settings1.Default.AExeSetting1);
    A.Settings1.Default.AExeSetting1 += "-";
    Console.ReadLine();
    A.Settings1.Default.Save();
}
```

B.exe:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A.Settings1.Default.AExeSetting1: {0}", A.Settings1.Default.AExeSetting1);
    A.Settings1.Default.AExeSetting1 += "-";
    Console.ReadLine();
    A.Settings1.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. However, this is very unfortunate and unexpected. I guess once again I have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Dear @wpfwannabe. I am looking for a solution so will help re-inventing it. This task, as you say, is trivial, and needs to be addressed.